# How many times does the word Tzitzit appear in Tanach?

Tags: tzitzis

I am looking for the word Tzitzit in Tanach (spelled any which way, but the word as it relates to tassels/strings.)

I so far have the obvious 3 from the [third passage of Shema](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.38?lang=bi&aliyot=0). So my count is at 3.

I am not looking for the word as it appears in the [fourth pasuk here](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15959/jewish/Chapter-28.htm), because according to the translation it means a very different word.

Further, I checked [the concordance here](https://books.google.com/books?id=80z4KOBCdUAC&pg=PT358&dq=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&hl=en&ei=FMQATuPbDdO30AG0wfG5Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&f=false), and could not find the word Tzitzit as spelled in Bamidbar, linked above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The concordance you link to has Num 15:38 15:39 Jer 48:9 and Eze 8:3 under this sense of the word. No one here is likely to have a better answer than a concordance.

Comment: Perhaps there will be other uses of the word corners as it pertains to garment/tassels and someone will know, which the concordance may have elsewhere.

Comment: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance/6734.%D7%A6%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A6%D6%B4%D7%AA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only appearances of that word are [Num 15:38–39](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.38-39?lang=bi) and [Ezek 8:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.8.3?lang=bi). The meaning in the latter verse is "mop of hair" (so HALOT), which is like the hanging strings of the familiar usage. The meaning of ציץ in [Jer 48:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.48.9?lang=bi) is uncertain, but some take it as wing/feather/fin, none of which are related to tassels (although they are things that are "hanging" off the side, so there's some semantic similarity). All other words with similar roots (ציץ, צו״ץ) have other meanings (and are found in Ex 28:36, 39:30, Lev 8:9, Num 17:23, Kings 1:6:18, 1:6:29, 1:6:32, 1:6:35, Is 27:6, 28:1, 28:4, 40:6, Ezek 7:10, Ps 72:16, 90:6, 92:8, 103:15, 132:18, Job 14:2, Song 2:9, Chr 2:20:16).

Source: Accordance word search, Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament (HALOT)